# onOptionsItemSelected called twice

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Running Android 5.0 on Nexus 5. My app uses `v4 Support Library 21.0.0`. `minSdkVersion` is 11 and `targetSdkVersion` is 21.

I have an activity deriving from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`. I have a number of menu items on the action bar. Now, if I quickly double-tap one of the action bar's menu items, `onOptionsItemSelected` is **called twice** resulting in two instances of my menu-triggered child ctivity! And yes, my menu handlers do return `true`.

I have googled this, but couldn't find anything. Am I facing a bug, or have I missed something? I've implemented this in the past, and never encountered this weird behavior. Ideas?

Comment: can you upgrade to support library 21.0.2?  might help

Comment: Tried that. Same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it happens in the latest support lib, but in the past, for any views, I've used this solution -

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

protected boolean isNotAFastClick() {
     boolean result = true;
     if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < FAST_CLICK_THRESHOLD) {
          result = false;
     }
     mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
     return result;
}
```

Before handling any click events, I just call the method to check if it was fast click.